# Sending response as Image instead of XML from server?

Tags: java, security, image-processing

Is it a good idea to send response from Server as Image instead of XML data to avoid data theft ?.

Answer (score 1):

No.
If you are concerned about theft, you should look at securing your data by using a certificate (https) / cryptography.

Sending an image would bloat the data being send( image being bigger than text) and also,how will you process it? It has to be manually or using OCR.

There are standard ways of protecting data using public private keys, you should look at that.

Comment: Though we use ssl to protect the data, the hacker renders the content as an valid user, proxies and manipulates the data and uses it his site. Therefore to avoid manipulation of data we thought of sending the the data as images which will be shown as it is and doesn’t require OCR.

Comment: Its not an ideal solution, but given your situation, its definitely worth a try. One or two more ways I could think of wont stand a chance against a skilled hacker.

Comment: In what ways do you think he can hack this solution and it would be great, if you can suggest an alternative method to protect  the data  ?

Comment: My first thought was to simple encode the data using a cipher and decode using Javascript. However, since the hacker is using it as a valid user, he will have access to the data in html form anyways. Another option is to change the way you show data, dont allow RAW XML stream, make it in distributed such that its hard to copy and paste, but again, you would have tried it if u could do that.